# Confirming that the value of a UITextField value is a member of an enum

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, enums

I have a `UITextField` With a `UIPickerView` to set its value from an `enum` and a save button the user presses to save their selection.

My question is, is there a way to error trap this setup so when the user presses save it will confirm that the value of the `UITextField` is a member of my enum?

My concern being the text field being left blank or having an alternate value pasted in.

Comment: Why not simply use a UIButton rather than a UITextField - use the button to display the picker view and then use the picker view value to set the button's title - Otherwise you will need to set the appropriate string as the "raw" value for the enumeration and check it when the user presses save

Comment: Why are you allowing the user to paste in (or type in) text if you are using a picker view to select only valid values?

Comment: I'm not allowing it, it may just be a bug in the simulator, but even when you have a textfield resign first responder to disable the keyboard you can double tap on the textfield and it becomes editable with the keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to type in a value, then it may be simpler to use a `UIButton` instead of a `UITextField` and update the button's label using the picker value.

However, you can easily use the enumeration's raw values to validate the input -

For example

```
enum Directions: String {
    case North = "North"
    case South = "South"
    case East = "East"
    case West = "West"
}

if let possibleDirection=Directions(rawValue: myTextField.text) {
    println("Valid direction")
}
else {
    println("Invalid direction")
}
```

would print "Valid direction" for a text field containing 'North' but "Invalid direction" for a text field containing 'Up'.

You may want to convert everything to lower case if you want 'north' to be an acceptable input.